# How to reshape layer in caffe with python?

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

It is possible to use [`"Reshape"`](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/tutorial/layers.html#reshape) layer within a prototxt file.
However, trying to use it in python (using `NetSpec()`):

```
n.resh = L.Reshape(n.fc3, reshape_param={'shape':'{dim:1 dim:1 dim:64 dim:64}'})
```

I got nothing but error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'BlobShape' object has no attribute 'append'
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
n.resh = L.Reshape(n.fc3, reshape_param={'shape':{'dim': [1, 1, 64, 64]}})
```

Note that the shape vector `[1, 1, 64, 64]` is passed as a list and not as a string like in the prototxt syntax.

In fact, any entry defined as `repeated` in `caffe.proto`, should be considered as a list/vector when interfacing using NetSpec.